# Wepack 5 My Components are Not Rendering Properly

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webpack, webpack-5

My Components are not rendering properly on the screen eventhough there are no errors in the console. I think I didnt configure my Webpack 5 well for production. This happens when I type in the terminal "yarn run dev-server" or "npm run serve"

Here are my scripts in package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "serve": "live-server public/",
    "build:dev": "webpack --mode development",
    "build:prod": "webpack --mode production --env production",
    "dev-server": "webpack serve --mode development --open",
    "test": "jest --config=jest.config.json"
},
```

Here is my webpack file (also not sure if I should separate them into different files):

```
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin"); 




module.exports = (env)=>{
    const isProduction = env === 'production';

    return {
       entry: './src/app.js', 
       output: {
          path:path.join(__dirname, 'public'), 
          filename:'bundle.js' 
      },
      module: {
        rules:[{
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/
        }, 
        {
            test: /\.s?css$/, 
            use: [
                MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                'css-loader',
                'sass-loader',
                // 'style-loader',
            ],
        }] 
      },
      plugins: [new MiniCssExtractPlugin()],
      devtool: isProduction ? 'source-map': 'eval-cheap-module-source-map', 
      performance: {
        hints: false,
        maxEntrypointSize: 512000,
        maxAssetSize: 512000
      },
      devServer: {
        static: path.join(__dirname, 'public'), 
        historyApiFallback: true 
      }
   };

};
```

Please let me know what I need to do.

Comment: Provide a minimal, reproducible component code

Comment: my repository: https://github.com/ilanhk/expensify